# Use PowerShell to automate website login and file download

Tags: powershell, download, automation, browser-automation

I want to use PowerShell to automate logging in to a website and downloading a PDF file. There are loads of examples on the internet that show how to do this (using `Invoke-WebRequest`, `WebClient`, `HttpWebRequest`, or `InternetExplorer.Application`), but most don't require a login first. Some show it with login, but I can't get them to work. I'm close with using `InternetExplorer.Application`:

```
$username = "xxxxx"
$password = "yyyyy"
$url = "https://example.com/login.aspx"
$usernameElementId = "aaaaa"
$passwordElementId = "bbbbb"
$submitButtonElementId = "ccccc"

$ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.Visible = $true
$ie.Navigate($url)

while($ie.ReadyState -ne 4 -or $ie.Busy) {Start-Sleep -m 100}

$ie.Document.getElementById($usernameControlId).value = $username
$ie.Document.getElementById($passwordControlId).value = $password
$ie.Document.getElementById($submitButtonElementId).click()

while($ie.ReadyState -ne 4 -or $ie.Busy) {Start-Sleep -m 100}
Start-Sleep -m 2000

$url = "https://example.com/statements/201607.pdf"
$outFilePath = "C:\Downloads\Statement_201607.pdf"
$ie.Navigate($url)

while($ie.ReadyState -ne 4 -or $ie.Busy) {Start-Sleep -m 100}

# Script works up to this point--the pdf document is shown in IE.
#The file downloaded in the next step is empty.

$ie.Document.body | Out-File -FilePath $outFilePath
```

My question: how do I get the PDF document downloaded in the last step of the script?

I've tried to do this same task with `WebClient` and `Invoke-WebRequest`, but I keep getting errors, because of the authentication piece. I've tried capturing the cookies after login and passing them with the next request, but nothing. If someone has a working example of doing this using another means, I'm all ears. In fact my preference would be to avoid automating IE, if possible, but I'll take any working solution.

Comment: In theory is as simple as `Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $pdfuri -Credential $cred -OutFile $outpath`, I use this all the time, but it's possible the website doesn't allow logging in this way.

Comment: @Deadly-Bagel I've seen that, but how do I create the `$cred` object? Note that I'm logging in to an external website. This isn't an Active Directory login or remote server login using AD credentials. I'd love to do it using `Invoke-WebRequest` if I can get the credentials working.

Comment: @neizan you can run it as is first to test that it will work with the example site.  Having the unset variable $cred will prompt for credentials.  While it is a standard windows credential prompt, the same method is used frequently for things not related to AD or even windows logins.

Comment: There's a few ways to create a cred object, you can even substitute it with the username and it will just prompt for a password, recommend googling `pscredential` for options. Looking into the IE path, doesn't look possible. When you open a PDF it actually just runs a plugin to show it so yeah the body will be blank or null. and there's only one means of invoking a "save as" on a link but it's real messy... Involves simulating keypresses, blegh.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally you would be able to use `Invoke-WebRequest` as you have said, however this really depends on how the website is set up. If it's just querying a database for the login and generating a cookie from that, it's likely not possible (but still worth a shot):

```
$url = "https://example.com/statements/201607.pdf"
$outFilePath = "C:\Downloads\Statement_201607.pdf"

# Prompt for password
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Credential MyUser -OutFile $outFilePath
# MyUser can be substituted with a credential object but it's complex, Google it
```

Heck, try it without the Credential parameter at all, again depending on the site it might be publicly available (just not accessible).

Depending on the site they may have some APIs to download it, contact them at your discretion:

```
$proxy = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri "https://example.com/webservices.asmx" -Credential MyUser
# Again MyUser can be substituted with a credential object
$proxy.GetMyStatement("201607") | Out-File $outFilePath
# Name and syntax depend on how it is designed and may vary wildly from example
```

And as a last resort...

```
#Wait for Download Dialog box to pop up
Sleep 5
while($ie.Busy){Sleep 1} 
#------------------------------
#Hit "S" on the keyboard to hit the "Save" button on the download box
$obj = new-object -com WScript.Shell
$obj.AppActivate('Internet Explorer')
$obj.SendKeys('s')

#Hit "Enter" to save the file
$obj.SendKeys('{Enter}')

#Closes IE Downloads window
$obj.SendKeys('{TAB}')
$obj.SendKeys('{TAB}')
$obj.SendKeys('{TAB}')
$obj.SendKeys('{Enter}')
```

Note you will need to disable any in-browser PDF viewers so that it treats it as a standard download, in IE11 this can be tricky as it's managed by the PDF viewers. If you're using Adobe Reader seems you need to uninstall the BrowserIntegration feature. Basically when you manually click on it, you want to get the "Run or Save?" option.